# Can't load RDF dataset with Jena on Android

Tags: android, sparql, rdf, jena, fuseki

I have a project using semantic web on android and i've been using jena-android (https://github.com/sbrunk/jena-android).
My problem comes when loading a dataset (that i have uploaded on jena fuseki), I don't have any result with the following instruction:

`QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService("http://localhost:3030/ds/query", query);`

I have executed the same code in pure Java (using eclipse) and it perfectly works.

So any ideas why ?

Comment: localhost would work on your local machine, but is unlikely to work on the android device....

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.You're actually right, but I've also tried to use 192.168.1.4 (which is my local adress). It doesn't work either. Even though the fuseki page DOES show up on the android device at this address